# Executar arquivo com python kivy

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo uma manutenção de crud usando python/kivy. 
São quatro arquivos main, um pra tabela P, outro pra A, e outro pra C.
O quarto arquivo main é o da tela principal que vai ter três botões pra você escolher qual tabela editar e, quando clicado nesse botão, executa o main da tabela selecionada.
Porem eu não lembro como eu faço pra executar um arquivo quando o botão for clicado. 
Segue o código main em python:

```
import kivy
from main_Aluno.py import Manutencao_A
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button 

class TelaPrincipal(App):
    pass

class Button(BoxLayout):
    def clickA(self)
        return main_Aluno.py
    def clickP(self):
        return main_Professor.py
    def clickC(self): 
        return main_Curso.py

botao = TelaPrincipal()
botao.run()
```

Obs: Manuitencao_A é a classe que contém o main A

Não sei se é relevante mas segue o código em kivy também:

```
<Button@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: vertical

    Label:
        text: "Escolha a tela a ser editada"
    Button: 
        text: "Alunos"
        on_press: root.clickA()
    Button:
        text: "Professores" 
        on_press: root.clickP()
    Button:
        text: "Cursos"
        on_press: root.clickC()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve está querendo executar os arquivos através de funções importando as classes não é?

```
import kivy
import main_Aluno, main_Professor, main_Curso
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button 

class TelaPrincipal(App):
    pass

class MainButtons(Button):
    def clickA(self):
        main_Aluno.funcaoA()
    def clickP(self):
        main_Professor.funcaoP()
    def clickC(self): 
        main_Curso.funcaoC()

botao = TelaPrincipal()
botao.run()
```

Arquivo kv

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: vertical

    Label:
        text: "Escolha a tela a ser editada"
    MainButtons: 
        text: "Alunos"
        on_press: self.clickA()
    MainButtons:
        text: "Professores" 
        on_press: self.clickP()
    MainButtons:
        text: "Cursos"
        on_press: self.clickC()
```